# How to change facebook share description?

Tags: facebook, share, social-networking, permalinks

Is there a way to change the facebook description of this page: http://goo.gl/Z103ve

Now after sharing it starts with the left column description like:

```
23 september, 2014 Nieuws 0 Reacties Share on TwitterShare on Facebook
```

I want to get rid of the above and start the share with the Title of the page.

At the moment I am using this line of code:

```
<a class="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Share on Facebook','extensio'); ?>"><?php _e('Share on Facebook','extensio'); ?></a>
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 2):

sharer.php only takes the URL as parameter, everything else will get read from the Open Graph Tags. Just add a description tag:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Whatever you want to show" />
```